# AngularJS: POST method with basic auth ( username and password) and content type in headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, post, basic-authentication

I am trying to make a POST request in AngularJS to a URL which has a basic authorization with username and password and i am getting a error 403 forbidden status code.

My question is where do the username and password go in the $http request ??

And how are written in ?? I mean regular "username:password" or Base64 encoded username and password.

My Controller Code is Below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
myApp.config(function ($routeProvider,$httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
})
.when('/login', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/login.html'
})

.when('/register', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/register.html'
})
.otherwise({
  redirectTo: '/'
});
});

myApp.controller('globalController', function($scope, $http){

$scope.formemail={};
$scope.user=username;
$scope.password=password;
$scope.validateemail = function(){
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://supportURL/'+$scope.formemail.validation+'/',
data:  {user:$scope.user, password:$scope.password}
  })
.then(function successCallback(response) {
  $scope.validateddata = response.data;
});
}});
```

My view code is below:

```
<div class="centerclass">
<form ng-submit="validateemail()">
 E-mail:
<input type="E-mail" ng-model="formemail.validation" placeholder="enter email id"><br><br>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Validate</button>
 </form><br><br>
</div>
<div class="centerclass">
<h1>RESULT:</h1><br>
<h2>{{validateddata}}</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: you can add atrribute data and pass like an object: {user$scope.user, password:$scope.password}

Comment: the view you share is a email validator, not user password form.

Comment: Yep.. I made few changes but still not working right .. 401 unauthorized !

Comment: the api you consums you made it ? ... if yes check interface contract to see was expect for data in, and what suppose to return.

Comment: are you trying to do some login form o some kind of it?

Comment: I am using 3rd party api and i also have my CORS extension in chrome running up (pretty sure thats not the problem) and i have that api working in the POSTMAN, but not in this angular project.

Comment: what parametres do you send in POSTMAN that works ?

Comment: Only 2 headers in POSTMAN that are passed.
1. Authorization (key) - Basic cHadfaafsf (value)
2.  Content-Type (key) - application/json (value)

Comment: are you sure ? not body data ? or something else?, in the browser the 401 or 403 are from POST or OPTIONS ? and headers values wich are?

Comment: 401 Status is not from POST reponse body its from OPTIONS.

Comment: has i suspect. the problem its cors

Comment: its not CORS i have another 3rd party api which makes a GET request successful. With the same code.

Comment: its cors from the api you want call. the othe api may have allow options method. and the api you call not.

Comment: the api needs to allow OPTIONS

Comment: in postman will work cause it send directly the post.  in the angular awlays sends OPTIONS from browser, thats why api need to allow CORS not your app the api.

Comment: Okay Understood ! I didn't think of that ! But still Thanks for helping me out !

Comment: try to check the api you try to consums and verify if has allow OPTIONS, and responding the question instead, in your POST in the block where method and url you put data: and can pass an object with user, and password like say in the first comment. Good Luck.!